# How to get all ordered values from immutable.js orderedmap without toJS?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have such an orderedmap like this:

```
{
 "200": { id: 200, name: "John" },
 "120": { id: 120, name: "Mike" },
 "350": { id: 350, name: "James" }
}
```

How to get all ordered values ​​without toJS method?
I've tried:

```
map.valueSeq().toArray(), Array.from(map.values())
```

but it returns an `intermixed array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `toList()`to get all the `values` (e.i. not the `keys`) of the map in a `List` immutable structure you can further manipulate later, or do `List(yourMap)` if you want the `key` and  `value` as a tuple array of sorts. Per the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/toList):

> This is similar to List(collection), but provided to allow for chained expressions. However, when called on Map or other keyed collections, collection.toList() discards the keys and creates a list of only the values, whereas List(collection) creates a list of entry tuples.
>
> `const { Map, List } = require('immutable')
>   var myMap = Map({ a: 'Apple', b: 'Banana' })
>   List(myMap) // List [ [ "a", "Apple" ], [ "b", "Banana" ] ]
>   myMap.toList() // List [ "Apple", "Banana" ]`

---

### Aclaration:

Javascript will sort your source `object` keys if they are numeric or parseable as numeric, so you can do the following workaround:

```
const PeopleMap = new OrderedMap([
 ["200", { id: 200, name: "John" }],
 ["120", { id: 120, name: "Mike" }],
 ["350", { id: 350, name: "James" }]
]);
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8kbcyfsn/

By declaring it as a key value pair array, the ordered map registers the right order.

Whereas if you declare it as an object,

```
const PeopleMap = new OrderedMap({
 "200": { id: 200, name: "John" },
 "120": { id: 120, name: "Mike" },
 "350", { id: 350, name: "James"}
});
```

It will attempt to order it by the `Number(key)` value.

Comment: You are right, however if you check this fork https://jsfiddle.net/y56nw384/ you can see if you use a non numeric string, it works. I think there's something about the way OrderedMap works that it tries to sort if the key is number like.

Comment: I think this solves the issue. It's not that the things you do are wrong, it's that OrderedMap behaves weirdly when the keys are parseable as numeric.

Comment: Thank you. Of course, javascript sort the numeric keys in ascending order. Numerc keys - it is a bad idea for ordered object. https://jsfiddle.net/6mtrhap8/2/

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect what should've been obvious that you pointed out: it's javascript's object that's messing things up, not OrderedMap itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if I did, you could try:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
```